# I want to change class of text field and add a feedback message when input length is between 1 and 20 but I can't find out why it is not working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

This is the code. I am using bootstrap valid and invalid classes to change input design once the length is valid and adding a feedback message.

When I run it the function doesn't work and the input field stays the same!

```js
var name = document.getElementById("name");
var validFB = document.getELementById("valid-feedback");
var invalidFB = document.getElementById("invalid-feeback");
name.onblur = function lengthCheck() {
  if (name.length > 1 && name.length < 20) {
    name.classList.remove("form-control");
    name.classList.add("form-control is-valid")
    validFB.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    name.classList.remove("form-control");
    name.classList.add("form-control is-invalid");
    invalidFB.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label for="validationServer01" class="form-label">First name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required>
  <div class="valid-feedback" style="display:none;">
    Looks good!
  </div>
  <div class="invalid-feedback" style="display:none;">
    Length should not exceed 50 characters.
  </div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label for="validationServer02" class="form-label">Last name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required>
  <div class="valid-feedback" style="display:none;">
    Looks good!
  </div>
  <div class="invalid-feedback" style="display:none;">
    Length should not exceed 50 characters.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, _specific_ question. Don't just list what you want.

Comment: Did you notice the error in the console? You have a typo. A good editor would have made that apparent, but you should be watching the console when working with JavaScript.

Comment: I am using visual studio to write html and js it gave 0 errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were multiple errors in your post.

## Bad syntax

First, you were once using `document.getELementById(..)` instead of `document.getElementById(..)` (there was one upper L which cause syntax error)

You should read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to better understand syntax and how it works.

## Multiples Ids

In your code you were using the same ID value for multiple elements which may cause collision in the future.

> An identifier is a name that identifies (that is, labels the identity of) either a unique object or a unique class of objects

I encourage you using different IDs for all of your HTML tags.

## Input value

To check the input length, you were using `name.length` but, here `name` is an HTML element and not a string as you were expected.
To retrieve the value of an input you should use `name.value` and then use `name.value.length` to check the value.

## Adding class names

You were trying to add multiple class names at once with `classList.add(..)` which cause the following error :

> Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('class1 class2') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.

## Conclusion

Your snippets contains multiple error that you better handle one at the time. You should open you console when you're coding (with ctrl+f12) and check the error while you are coding.

#### EDIT

I also change `name.onblur` to `name.addEventListener('blur',...)` which is more easy to use in my opinion. You can check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) here !

```js
let name = document.getElementById("firstName")
let invalidFB = document.getElementById("invalid-feedback-first-name")
let validFB = document.getElementById("valid-feedback-first-name")
name.addEventListener("blur",function(){
  if (name.value.length > 1 && name.value.length < 20) {
    name.classList.add("form-control");
    name.classList.add("is-valid")
    validFB.style.display = "block";
    invalidFB.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    name.classList.remove("form-control");
    name.classList.add("form-control");
    name.classList.add("is-invalid")
    invalidFB.style.display = "block";
    validFB.style.display = "none";
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label for="validationServer01" class="form-label">First name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" required>
  <div class="valid-feedback" style="display:none;" id="valid-feedback-first-name">
    Looks good!
  </div>
  <div class="invalid-feedback" style="display:none;" id="invalid-feedback-first-name">
    Length should not exceed 50 characters.
  </div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label for="validationServer02" class="form-label">Last name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" required>
  <div class="valid-feedback" style="display:none;">
    Looks good!
  </div>
  <div class="invalid-feedback" style="display:none;">
    Length should not exceed 50 characters.
  </div>
</div>
```